# Scala application running in Eclipse but not as a jar

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven, log4j2

I have a Scala application (maven based) which is running fine till yesterday. Today I tried to add the log4j2 functionality to it. I added the required maven dependencies and the corresponding configurations (`log4j2.xml`). I created a small scala program which writes simple `logger.info` message. It is running fine from Eclipse. I used `mvn package` to generate the jar with dependencies. When I run it from command line, it giving me an exception saying "`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractAppender`". I can see the log4j class files in the exported jar. Also, I can see the dependency jars(`log4j-core`, `log4j-api`) in the `Project -> Configure Build Path` window. I also deleted the `.m2` folder and `clean build` the project. What am I missing here? Please help me out. Below is my `pom.xml` file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>datamover</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>BI - Data Mover</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/applicationinsights-logging-log4j2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>applicationinsights-logging-log4j2</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api-scala_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>11.0</version>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.10 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-hive -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId> <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId> 
            <version>2.1.0</version> </dependency> -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.databricks/spark-avro_2.10 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-avro_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.11 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-data-lake-store-sdk -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-data-lake-store-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.2.jre8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-nop -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.databricks/spark-csv_2.10 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-csv_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.test.bi.ScalaLogTestV2</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                        <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <description>Spark application to move data folders.</description>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you are working with eclipse IDE.
Please try this approach.
Go to Project properties -> Deployment assembly and ensure that the maven dependencies entry is included.

I've seen that this configuration gets missed whenever you execute Maven -> Update Project.

Comment: I don't have such option because it's not a faceted project. It is a maven Spark project using Scala language.